# Rejected change as defacing, while there isn't any defacing

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals, documentation-review

I proposed [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/133743?filter-tags=android). I've just improved some aspects in [Creating a New Project](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/85/getting-started-with-android/537/creating-a-new-project#t=201703290857349018637) example and added another example: *Setting up AVD (Android Virtual Device)*. It was rejected by two users with this comment:

> Introduces spam, defaces the page in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

[image: Review]

**My question is**: could someone explain me where is **spam**, **defacing**, or **something inappropriate** in my edit? Because I can't find any.

---

**Update:** [Proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/133747) this change again and it was approved. Something is really wrong with the reviewers.

Comment: That seems like a _good_ edit. No idea why those users thought it'd be a good idea to reject it.

Comment: @Cerbrus So what should I do? Propose it again?

Comment: I'd say so, yea.

Comment: Proposed it again: [proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/133747).

Comment: Now it just needs some more users to approve it.

Comment: **What?** "*Includes factually incorrect information. it is trying to delete useful info*"

Comment: What's up with the reviewers in android docs?!

Comment: Thanks! It was approved.

Comment: . . . Probably they think the way the preview is formatted, sudo is removing useful content. @Cerb

Comment: Is robo-rejecting a thing now?

Comment: @Pekka웃 we just need to fine-tune the robos to robo-reject the crap and robo-approve the goodies...

Comment: Bah, I would have rejected the edit for introducing too much readability.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: https://xkcd.com/810/ maybe?